# Store Data in an HTML file

Tags: html

Wanted to know if the following scenario is possible -

I have some data that is in an excel file. I want to make an html page which will have this data inside it (no other source of data). And inside the Html page, will I be able to put textfields, buttons etc for a user to input data and based on that, i need to write queries (jqueries i guess) to show the data that is the result of those queries

Can this be done? I have not done anything so far. I just wanted to know if this is possible and please someone point me in the right direction for me to start. I wanna learn on my own how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (if it can be done is the question)HTML5 local storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp 
Web storage is only supported in Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML is a markup language - it is the structure of a webpage, and has no mechanisms for storing or processing dynamic data.

You will have to use a client-side language JavaScript + cookies, or a server-side language like PHP + MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at using JavaScript in the page.  On the server (I presume) you need to read the Excel file, and generate JS objects on the page that hold the values.  That is, the JS when run creates a collection of JS objects with the values in it.  This script can be embedded in the page so that no other data access is needed.

You can then write more JS linked to the buttons that select data out of these objects, and displays them on the page.  You probably don't want to do this from scratch -- there are good JS libraries and frameworks to leverage.  Consider either GWM or YUI.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way is to open the file in Excel and save it as text (tab-separated; comma-separated would do, too), then insert this text data into your HTML document between the tags `<script type="text/plain">` and `</script>`. You can then write, in a rather straighforward way, JavaScript code that reads the content of this element and constructs a JavaScript array of objects (or some other suitable data structire) from it. It will then be easy to access the data in JavaScript.

This will make it possible to run queries and display data. Modifying the data would be a completely different matter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know i am replying after a long time but will try it out. Didn't have to work on this that day. Now i have to.